# ANGULAR-CLI - VISUAL CODE: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'NODE_DEBUG' of undefined

Tags: visual-studio-code, angular-cli

I have an app developed with Angular-CLI using Visual Code:

```
  angular/cli: 9.0.3,
  npm: '6.14.8',
  ares: '1.16.1',
  brotli: '1.0.9',
  cldr: '37.0',
  icu: '67.1',
  llhttp: '2.1.3',
  modules: '83',
  napi: '7',
  nghttp2: '1.41.0',
  node: '14.15.0',
  openssl: '1.1.1g',
  tz: '2020a',
  unicode: '13.0',
  uv: '1.40.0',
  v8: '8.4.371.19-node.17',
  zlib: '1.2.11'
```

I have been compiling and running my app for years with no problems and suddenly after a successful compile:

```
$ ng serve

chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 6.16 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 233 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.15 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {scripts} scripts.js, scripts.js.map (scripts) 1.1 MB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 1.58 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 13.9 MB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2020-11-05T17:58:57.468Z - Hash: fc25bd5314199aca3ed8 - Time: 56147ms
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
: Compiled successfully.
```

the application hangs and I get the following error message in the browser inspector:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'NODE_DEBUG' of undefined
    at Object../node_modules/util/util.js (util.js:109)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Object../node_modules/bl/bl.js (bl.js:3)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Object../node_modules/msgpack5/index.js (index.js:5)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Object../node_modules/autobahn/lib/autobahn.js (autobahn.js:22)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Object../node_modules/autobahn/index.js (index.js:14)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
```

I am sorry I cannot give you more details but I am really clueless. A google search does not even produce a meaningful link to follow to try to fix the problem. I wonder if someone has stumbled on the same problem and can direct me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Right, after running an "ng build" I found warnings about crypto-js library.

I had to install crypto-js V3.3.0 to have my app working again. latest release of the library will not work.

Hope this will help someone but  if you can explain why this worked feel free to add to my answer.

Comment: I have this same issue!  What version of crypto-js are you currently using now?  I have an Angular 13 app that I just upgraded to and now the site won't run with that node_debug error